# Google maps - Viewport showing markers from database content

Tags: ajax, google-maps

I need help to display markers on viewport where markers informations (title, lat, lng ..) are based in a database. I based my work on the https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers tutorial but when i arrive to the part where i need to call my server i have problems.

Here is my script which execute on idle.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', showMarkers);

function showMarkers(str) {
var bounds = map.getBounds();

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else { // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

  var locations =  xmlhttp.responseText;

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),        
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
}
}
 xmlhttp.open("GET","locations.php?lat1="+bounds.getNorthEast().lat()+"&lat2="+bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

here is my locations.php file

```
<?php 
$lat1 = $_GET['lat1'];
$lat2 = $_GET['lat2'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE lat BETWEEN '".$lat2."' AND '".$lat1."'";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 echo '[';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
   echo "['".$row['title']." , ".$row['lat']." , ".$row['lng']."]";
 }
 echo']';
 ?>
```

The problem I think is that i want the response of the locations.php to be an array, but the xmlhttp.responseText convert the array to a string. Do you have a solution to get a string back from my locations.php ?
I have already tried to split my string to get an array but it doesn't work really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to ensure that the response is valid JSON use `json_encode()`

   ```
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   $arr = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $arr[] = array($row['title'], $row['lat'], $row['lng']);
    }  

   echo json_encode($arr);
   ```
2. use `JSON.parse()` to convert the returned string into an array

   ```
   var locations =  JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   ```

Comment: is it possible to do an ajax call inside the first one ? I have stil an array in my php script.
      `$.ajax({ url: 'product_info.php',data: {id: locations[i][0]},type: 'post',success: function(output) {alert(output);}});`

Comment: what do you mean by "first one"?

Comment: i mean in the one where i get the location=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) i make a second call to select other data from database with a data of my location array for example. But i don't suceed to get the good array in response, it's repeat me the first array (location array()). The second array i call from the second ajax call is called product_info. How do i do to get the product_info array ?